# Yun as a Conventional Wireless Access Point

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun

I want my YUN to act as a server in a client/server architecture so students can control their wifi robots via their desktops. I can plug the YUN directly into an ethernet port on our network and want to have robots communicate with it through a client/server architecture. Can somebody steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/Vadorequest/AAD1), made by @Vadorequest the early days of the Yun: he hacked a car to control it via his smartphone. There's a [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amPQWXRpA-A) on youtube.

Comment: The video wasn't very informative, but it did provide proof of concept. If you have a link to the process this French gentleman used to make the car run, I would appreciate it. I understand the phone part, at least through Bluetooth. I am looking for an interface to Node.js to allow users to control the car. More detail would help.

Comment: I apologize. You did provide a link to the project. Thanks!